# How do I make this view With bootstrap grid? or should I use list-group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I used col-md-4 and but The "more" button doesn't remain fixed in position. I want the border to be in bottom on mobile view and on side of  in tab or desktop view as shown in the pictures.

```html
     <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
                    <div class="texts">
                        <h4>Latest News</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">More</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                    <div class="texts">    
                        <h4>Feel free to Communicate</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="texts">    
                        <h4>Our facilities</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Desktop View]

[image: Mobile View]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `float: right`?

Comment: first of all where you want `more` button, in which position you need to fix button like center, left ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  .borderstyle{
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
  .borderstyle{
    border-right :none
  }
  }

  
  media
</style>
  </head>
  <body><div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="texts borderstyle">
                        <h4>Latest News</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">More</button>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <hr class="d-none d-lg-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="texts borderstyle" >    
                        <h4>Feel free to Communicate</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">More</button>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                              <hr class="d-none d-lg-block">
                    </div>
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-12 borderstyle">
                    <div class="texts">    
                        <h4>Our facilities</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            Suspendisse in metus mollis, 
                            tincidunt metus in, vulputate est. 
                            Donec ac aliquam augue. Vestibulum nec 
                            purus iaculis, placerat tortor eu, 
                            facilisis orci.
                        </p>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">More</button>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                              <hr class="d-none d-lg-block">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can use bootstrap class float-right to push the button to right of the div and for border you can use combination of 'hr tag' with border class visible on resposive breakpoint.

After achieving functionality you can beautify your html as you want ...:)

Comment: glad to help!! ...:)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the css property `float:right` to all your buttons

good luck!